# Is it possible to get a System.EntryPointNotFoundException without any native dlls?

Tags: c#

I'm getting such an exception and the exception text only reads "Entry point was not found"
The stacktrace just shows that the last call was to one of our own List implementations CSharpInterface.get_Children() method which is a normal c# property.

Doesnt "entry point" mean that it tries to find a main() method? What possible causes can something like this have?

```
Entry point was not found.
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at Company.Common.Tree.Interfaces.ChildrenEditable.ITreeChildrenEditable`1.get_Children()
   at AddIn.Network.Http.Client.HttpClient.Send(IMessage requestExchange)
   at AddIn.Core.AddInSideAdapter.Network.Client.ClientViewToContractAdapter.Send(IMessage exchange)
   at AddIn.Core.HostSideAdapter.Network.Client.ClientContractToViewAdapter.Send(IMessageExchange msgExchange)
   at Core.Instance.Service.MessageReceived(IMessage endpointExchanged)
```

Comment: You might want to show some code around what your own List implementation is doing. Also, expand on what your project type is (Class Library, Console, MVC) and when you see this error (start-up, button click etc). The more details you give us the more we can help you!

Comment: well it's a solution of over a hundred projects using MAF, so it's kind of hard to just show something small that is representable of all the root causes this could have. I was just interested to know if it CAN be a c# dll not being found? makes no sense to me, fusion log shows no binding errors regarding that dll.

Comment: It is possible, the CLR can generate this exception for managed code as well.  Pretty hard to guess at the underlying reason without anything to look at, it should be exceedingly rare since you'd normally get a MissingMethodException.  Looking at the CLR source code (VirtualCallStubManager::Resolver() generates it), best wild guess is a failure to resolve the implementation method for an interface method.  Ought to be a DLL Hell problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it appears to be a mix up of dlls but the exact problem does seem impossible to pinpoint. We have a webapp in a subdirectory of our main app and the main app seems to load dlls from the web apps directory for some reason. My colleague thought it would not create any issues because the dlls should be identical.. but as always, such a bad practice seems to have turned up a particularly nasty exception. The web app also runs on .net4.5 while the main app still runs on .net3.5. Like he said.. in theory it should work because the dlls being used are the same and .net3.5.

Comment: You cannot get help if you don't document the exception.  Posting the exception's stack trace is a minimum requirement.

Comment: There is nothing special in that stacktrace that's why I didnt post it but okay, I still added it to my original question. No inner exception either. It has to be a dll loading / version issue. VirtualCallStubManager::Resolver seems to be c++ code, I cant step into that like with http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ can I?

Comment: @HansPassant by the way, you already answered my question with your first comment, if you post that as an answer I will accept it.